# I use visual studio 2012 in windows 8 ASP design view shows Square for unicode characters

Tags: visual-studio-2012, unicode, persian, design-view, farsi

I really need help for this because when I write my code in source view, I have no problem but when I view it in design view it shows square instead of farsi characters. 
how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem here:

- make sure you have saved the final file with `utf-8 with signature` (file menu-> advanced save options)
- add `<meta charset="utf-8" />` to the head of the html page or your master page.
- also you need these meta tags too: `<meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="fa" />` and `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />`